# Android SimpleDateFormat Parsing Error

Tags: java, android, date

I know there are many other questions on stackoverflow that deal with SimpleDateFormatter in Android or Java, but I have been unable to find any questions that help me answer my own question.

I have a String with this time format `2014-06-28T21:00:00-05:00` and I am trying to convert it to `9:00 PM` (or at least 9:00). I'm pretty sure my issue is with actually writing out the correct notation for the above time, but here is my code:

```
        String input = '2014-06-28T21:00:00-05:00';
        DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+|-hh:mm");
        fromFormat.setLenient(false);
        DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        toFormat.setLenient(false);
        try{
            String output = toFormat.format(fromFormat.parse(input));
            return output;
        } catch(ParseException pe){
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "No Date Listed";
```

If I look at the stack trace, it tells me `unparseable date at offset #19`.

I am **fairly certain** the logic behind the code does work because I switched the SimpleDateFormats to something a little simpler like `yyyy-MM-dd` and `MMMM dd, yy` and it worked perfectly. So, can anyone point me in the right direction and help me figure out the proper time notation?

I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: what is -05:00 doing in there

Comment: I think that's a time zone at the end...

Comment: It is almost, but not quite, a timezone.

Comment: Try to replace this line:DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that you are being given a time with a time zone format which is not supported by `SimpleDateFormat`.

There are two supported time zone formats that it can parse,

General time zones:

```
General time zone: Time zones are interpreted as text if they have names. For time zones representing a GMT offset value, the following syntax is used:
     GMTOffsetTimeZone:
             GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
     Sign: one of
             + -
     Hours:
             Digit
             Digit Digit
     Minutes:
             Digit Digit
     Digit: one of
             0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Hours must be between 0 and 23, and Minutes must be between 00 and 59. The format is locale independent and digits must be taken from the Basic Latin block of the Unicode standard.
```

...and RFC 822 time zones:

```
RFC 822 time zone: For formatting, the RFC 822 4-digit time zone format is used:
     RFC822TimeZone:
             Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
     TwoDigitHours:
             Digit Digit
TwoDigitHours must be between 00 and 23. Other definitions are as for general time zones.
```

As you can see, the general time zone has a colon in it, but must be prefixed with "GMT", whereas the RFC 822 format has no colon.  What you are trying to parse is a sort of bastardization of the two.

One of the following would work, depending on the time zone format, *if* you had a legal syntax:

```
    String generalInput = "2014-06-28T21:00:00GMT-05:00"; // legal General time zone
    String rfcInput = "2014-06-28T21:00:00-0500"; // legal RFC 822 time zone

    DateFormat generalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"); // format for general time zone
    DateFormat rfcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); // format for RFC 822 time zone
```

Since your input is malformed, I would suggest that you simply don't try to parse the time zone part of it at all, and treat it as a local time.  Since you're trying to convert `21:00` to `9:00 pm` anyway, this should work for you:

```
    String input = "2014-06-28T21:00:00-05:00"; // not a legal time zone format
    DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); // don't even try to parse time zone
```

Comment: Perfect! And +1 for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following -

String input = '2014-06-28T21:00:00.000-0500';

```
    DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: As explained by @azurefrog, this would not work. Thank you anyways!