# SimpleDateFormat behaviour change in Android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have encountered an issue with date formatting on Android 6.0, Marshmallow. The code throwing the exception noted below is a pure-Java library (built separately) which my application uses for API requests ("the client"). The library is built with Java 1.6 if that is related...anyway, here is the code;

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd E hh:mm aa", Locale.UK);
Date eventDate = dateFormat.parse(StringUtils.substring(record, 0, 23).trim());
```

...the `record` has value;

```
2015-10-23 Fri 10:59 PM BST   3.60 meters
```

...which after "trimming" is;

```
2015-10-23 Fri 10:59 PM
yyyy-MM-dd E hh:mm aa
```

This code has worked since the good-old days of Froyo and is unit-tested. All that aside Marshmallow throws the exception;

```
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException: SynchroniseTidePosition.doInBackground
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-10-23 Fri 10:59 PM" (at offset 21)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at com.oceanlife.rover.handler.XTideParser.parseResponse(XTideParser.java:69)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at com.brantapps.oceanlife.task.SynchroniseTidePosition.doInBackground(SynchroniseTidePosition.java:107)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at com.brantapps.oceanlife.task.SynchroniseTidePosition.doInBackground(SynchroniseTidePosition.java:43)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-23 21:01:56.816 4091-4110/com.oceanlife E/ParseException:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Offset "21" is the space after the '9' in 10:59. Can anyone explain this failure?

*Update*

Switched over to joda-time and it spat out a more informative error message. Here it is;

```
Invalid format ... is malformed at "PM"
```

...so, this is about the AM/PM aspect of the string trying to be parsed - back to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Shot in the dark: can you confirm that your strings aren't in some UTF-8/UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang - strings are parsed with the Charset; Charset.forName("UTF-8")
What'cha thinking?

Comment: Sorry just throwing out ideas. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399846/android-simpledateformat-parsing-error (but wouldn't explain the prior unit test success) and this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158265. Again may be more noise than not so apologies if it is.

Comment: I've worked around it by looking for "AM" or "PM" and in the latter case adding twelve hours to the parsed date-time. It's definitely associated with the AM/PM aspect but will leave this question open to see if there is a reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The UK Locale appears to have had its definitions of "am" and "pm" altered.

In Marshmallow the UK Locale now has "am" represented as "a.m." and "pm" by "p.m."

```
String record = "2015-10-23 Fri 10:59 p.m. BST   3.60 meters"
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd E hh:mm aa", Locale.UK);

// note the length is 25 now, not 23... 
Date eventDate = dateFormat.parse(StringUtils.substring(record, 0, 25).trim());
```

I can't offer an explanation why, but the US Locale works with am/pm and the UK with a.m./p.m.

**Edit**

It appears that as part of the Locale updates in March 2015, the `en_gb` locale had its am/pm definitions replaced. [source diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/1b7d32f919554dda9c193b32188251337bc756f1%5E%21/icu4c/source/data/locales/en_GB.txt)

Comment: Thank you for this. I am just reverting my changes from last night to switch to the US locale to test.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanking you - tick and a +1. Pretty sure that this is going to be a popular answer as apps are updated to support Marshmallow. Good job. Now onto runtime permissions!