# Java Code Date Parsing In Android ParseException

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I need to parse date given in this format , Tested on Marshmallow on Nexus 5.

```
Nov 5, 2015, 03.44PM IST
```

I parsed it with Java SimpleDateFormat

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Star {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma z");

    Date today= new Date();

    Date date=null;
    try {
        date = format.parse("Nov 5, 2015, 03.44PM IST");

        Calendar calendarToday =Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarToday.setTime(today);

        Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);



        System.out.println(compareIgnoreTime(calendarToday,calendar));


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static int compareIgnoreTime(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
    if (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) != c2.get(Calendar.YEAR))
        return c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) != c2.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        return c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    return c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
}
```

Though this method throwing in Android Only

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Nov 5, 2015, 03.44PM IST" (at offset 22)
```

Comment: I think you have to use 'Z' instead of 'z' for the timezone designator, so the pattern would be "MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma Z"

Comment: If you take out the z (and IST), does it work?

If not, take out the z anyway and instead of `dd` use `d`. If it works, get the z (and IST) back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311144/simpledateformat-behaviour-change-in-android-marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

First get date and try to format, after you get valid date again formate it as per your requirement.

```
String dtStart = new Date().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
            SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma z");
            System.out.println(print.format(date));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```