# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-02-01 10:00pm" (at offset 16)

Tags: android, date-format

I want to change change Time format 12 hours to 24 hours.

I have a date String like this

```
    String date = "2016-02-01";
    String time = "10:00pm";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mmaa");

        DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date daaateee = null;
        String output = null;
        try{

            String ddd =date + " " + time;
            daaateee= df.parse(ddd);

            output = outputformat.format(daaateee);

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(ParseException pe){
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am trying to change like this but its show me Error :

```
System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-02-01 10:00pm" (at offset 16)
```

This code is working fine with all devices.but not working on Moto g3 which have marshmallow os. is there any reason not converting in marshmallow devices?

Help me to convert Time format 12H to 24H.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: As an aside, your code would be easier to read if you used more meaningful names than `ddd` and `daateee`.

Comment: your dateFormat needs to be `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");`

Comment: @Vihar: No it doesn't. There's no space in the input.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, my bad so that 'aa' needs to be 'a' without space

Comment: post your answer @Vihar

Comment: @RushangPrajapati it worked?

Comment: i am checking it @Vihar

Comment: @Vihar: `aa` works fine for me... admittedly I'm not testing it under Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date format for supporting am/pm needs to be 'a' rather than 'aa',

so you bascially need to do `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");`

Comment: its Working in simulator but not working in my device @Vihar

Comment: @RushangPrajapati: That would tie in with my answer, if your simulator defaults to English and your device uses another locale with a different am/pm specifier.

Comment: i got Another point this code is working fine with all devices.but not working on Moto g3 which have marshmellow os. is there any reason not converting in marshmellow devices ?? @JonSkeet #vihar

Comment: @RushangPrajapati: Not that I'm aware of, but that sounds like you should have given details about that in the original post.

Comment: @RushangPrajapati: And is it still a problem on that device after specifying the time zone, locale, and using `a` instead of `aa`?

Comment: yes i  still face problem in Moto g3 device i other device working good but i don't know why its not working in Moto g3  @JonSkeet

Comment: @RushangPrajapati: And have you isolated whether it's a) that specific device; b) all Moto g3 devices; c) all Marshamallow devices? Using the code in my answer, it really should be fine.

Comment: @RushangPrajapati maybe something has changed in marshmallow,can you please have a look at this link if at all it is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/33313385/2551236

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem *may* be that you're not specifying the locale - so it's using your system locale instead, which may have different am/pm specifiers. Here's an example which works for me in desktop Java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String date = "2016-02-01";
        String time = "10:00pm";
        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");

        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mmaa", Locale.US);
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
        Date parsed = inputFormat.parse(date + " " +time);
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
        System.out.println(outputFormat.format(parsed));
    }
}
```

Note that I'm also specifying the time zone as UTC, to avoid any issues with daylight saving time changes (where a date/time combination may be ambiguous or not exist at all).

If that still doesn't work for you under Android, try using `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mmaa"` instead of `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma"` - although I'd still *expect* the former pattern to work. It's definitely worth specifying the time zone and locale though.